# How to display subtitle with multiple lines in FSCalendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, fscalendar

I integrated FSCalendar via pod and encountered subtitle is being trimmed when it is large. I want it to be aligned in multiple lines instead of trimming.

To make it work as expected, if I do any modification in pod files it affects the update in the next time. So please direct me in the right path as how to achieve. Thanks.

Created a new ticket https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/issues/882

[image]

Comment: in FSCalendar Library, which calendar you are using ?

Comment: @NiravKotecha RangePicker

Comment: in library, there is no sub title. i think you have putted label..? if putted label then can you given `numberOfLines=0` to that label ?

Comment: No we need to add this 
`-(NSString*)calendar:(FSCalendar *)calendar subtitleForDate:(NSDate *)date` to get the subtitle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods that return an image in a cell. Create an image with the multiple lines of text printed in it.